# taking data from a user on android using edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to get names form a user using an editext  object, now to get all three names from a user, should i use three editext objects or is ther a way to split an editext object to take three separate text inputs?   Later i pass the data to anothe function which will print it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a single EditText
2. Input the name like this --> Kumar Vivek Mitra
3. Then store it in a String.

   `String name = "Kumar Vivek Mitra";`
4. Use split() method.

   `String[] temp = name.split(" ");     // SPLIT ON BASIS OF SPACE`
5. You have all the 3 portion of name separated

   `System.out.println("First Name: "+temp[0]);`

   `System.out.println("Middle Name: "+temp[1]);`

   `System.out.println("Last Name: "+temp[2]);`

Answer (score 2):

its better to take 3 `EditTexts` for three different inputs. for names, I will suggest to use 3 EditTexts in a horizontal `LinearLayout` with `weight=1` for `EditTexts` and `weight=3` for parent `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

If you need three different edit text boxes, then you'll need to use three different EditText widgets.

You could also use only one EditText and split the string later, that would probably be easier for the user to type instead of moving from one box to the next.